# Prove that $\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{a}{8b+c}}\ge 1$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

Prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{8b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{8c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{8a+b}}\ge 1$$ where $a,b,c>0$

---

Here is my idea. Please check it for me. Thanks a lot.

Let $$x=\sqrt{\frac{9a}{8b+c}};y=\sqrt{\frac{9b}{8c+a}};z=\sqrt{\frac{9c}{8a+b}}\left(x;y;z\ge 0\right)$$

By Laplace formula we have: $$\begin{vmatrix}-9&8x^2&x^2\\y^2&-9&8y^2\\8z^2&z^2&-9\end{vmatrix}=0$$

$$0=\left(-1\right)^{1+1}\cdot \left(-9\right)\cdot \begin{vmatrix}-9&8y^2\\z^2&-9\end{vmatrix}+\left(-1\right)^{2+1}\cdot y^2\cdot \begin{vmatrix}8x^2&x^2\\z^2&-9\end{vmatrix}+\left(-1\right)^{3+1}\cdot 8z^2\cdot \begin{vmatrix}8x^2&x^2\\-9&8y^2\end{vmatrix}$$

Or $$81=8\left(y^2z^2+x^2y^2+z^2x^2\right)+57x^2y^2z^2$$

And we need to prove $x+y+z\ge 3$

I will solve it by contradiction. indeed, let $x+y+z<3$ and $x=ka';y=kb';z=kc'(a';b';c'\ge 0)$ such that $a'+b'+c'=3$ and $0<k<1$

It is easy to show $$8(\sum_{cyc} a'^2b'^2)+57\Pi_{cyc} a'^2>81$$

By contradiction i'll prove that $$8(a'^2b'^2+b'^2c'^2+c'^2a'^2)+57(a'^2b'^2c'^2)\le 81$$

Let $a'+b'+c'=3u;a'b'+b'c'+c'a'=3v^2;a'b'c'=w^3$

The last inequality equivalent to

$$f(w^3)=-57w^6-8\left(9v^2-6uw^3\right)+81\ge 0$$

See that $f''(w^3)\le 0$ which says that $f$ is concave function and it gets a minimal value of $w^3$

By $uvw$ we will prove in

+)$w^3=0$. Assume $a'=0$

$$b'^2c'^2\le \frac{81}{8}$$ which is true by AM-GM

+)Assume $a'=b'$

$$-\left(a'-c'\right)^2\left(32a'^4+224a'^3c'+71a'^2c'^2+14a'c'^3+c'^4\right)\le 0$$

Comment: Why is the determinant 0?  And deleting a question after receiving an answer is rude and generally frown upon.

Comment: @user10354138 The determinant is $0$ because this system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @DVdivi If you want to delete your topic, so I don't want to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Guys, please help me to check it.

Comment: I will not delete my question. Pls help me.